# Nested Callback arguments and naming conventions

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a piece of code that has nested call backs.  Each callback has a response.  One is name res and one is named execRes.

Is there a wide spread convention of naming these same name variables?  Or is it up to the discretion of the programmer?

```
app.post('/url', upload.array(), function(req, res, next) {
  returnsModel.find().where().exec((execErr, execRes) => {
    if (execErr) {
      res.send(500, {
        error: execErr
      });
      console.log(execErr);
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(execRes));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(execRes));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Naming conventions are project/user specific. You should document and keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should name callbacks according to its semantic. While `res` is a common name for express route callbcak, mongoose requests callbacks might be named according to its models, like `birdModel.find().exec((err, birds)=>{})`

Answer (score 0):

I think a common issue is the abbreviation of `response` and `result` to `res`. `response` or `res` should be reserved for the server route as most/all servers feature `request` (`req`) and `response` and these are very specific things. As mentioned previously, other variables should also be named after what they are, avoiding generic terms like `res` or `result`.

```
app.post('/url', upload.array(), function(request, response, next) {
  returnsModel.find().where().exec((err, model) => {
    if (err) {
      response.send(500, {
        error: err
      });
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      response.send(JSON.stringify(model));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(model));
    }
  });
});
```